# ImportError: No module named _bsddb

Tags: python, importerror

I had some problems with upgrading matplotlib recently so I ended up installing different versions of Python on my Mac (Sierra) via brew, and then uninstalled afterwards. However, now matplotlib works (2.0.2) but whenever I run a particular python script that used to work I get an error which I didn't have before:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sim.py", line 254, in <module>
    main()
  File "sim.py", line 118, in main
    db = shelve.open('.sim_balance', 'c')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 243, in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 227, in __init__
    Shelf.__init__(self, anydbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/anydbm.py", line 84, in open
    mod = __import__(result)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/dbhash.py", line 7, in <module>
    import bsddb
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/bsddb/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    import _bsddb
ImportError: No module named _bsddb
```

According to my searches online this has something to do with my brew installed python interfering? I also deleted all my files in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` yesterday which may have caused this as well.

I have tried homebrew `brew install berkeley-db` but then `pip install bsddb3` yields:

```
Terrys-MBP:site-packages Terry$ pip install bsddb3
Collecting bsddb3
  Using cached bsddb3-6.2.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Can't find a local Berkeley DB installation.
    (suggestion: try the --berkeley-db=/path/to/bsddb option)

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/m5/1fg5rnj11_9cz5pntlqlwzyc0000gn/T/pip-build-elBAFK/bsddb3/
```

EDIT: Solved. Installed anaconda, installed bsddb via `conda install` and everything is working now.

Comment: You should answer your own question with the EDIT. it helps maintain the question answer format.

Comment: Furthermore, you can accept  your own answer in case you didn't know.

Comment: Apparently my answer does not meet the quality requirements. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. I Installed anaconda, installed bsddb via conda install and everything is working now.

Comment: For Windows you have to use another channel:
`conda install -c cryoem bsddb3`

https://anaconda.org/cryoem/bsddb3